# Convert java code that returns object with template into c++ using jni

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I need to call some java code from C++ using JNI.

I can't figure out how to get a value from a returned java generic with JNI. Java code that I need to call from C++ is:

```
encoderCapabilities.getQualityRange().getLower()
```

The problem is java returns the generic type `Range<Integer>`:

```
public Range<Integer> getQualityRange ()
```

I tried to use following C++ code, but it crash:

`GetMethodID` and `CallObjectMethodV` with function name `getQualityRange` and arguments `()Landroid/util/Range;`. It seems did not crash, but next call crash:

`getLower`, `()I`

Could you please suggest what code can work?

The object Range is fine as its method toString returns valid string "[1,100]", but "getLower" failed on getting methods.
Upd: The Answer from Botje works!

Comment: You should post the full C++ code where you call this Java method, not just fragments of it. And you should also post the (symbolized) stacktrace from the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After type erasure, `Range#getLower` will have declared type `Comparable`, regardless of what the type in the Java source was.

Try this instead:

```
jobject range = ...;
jclass cls_Range = env->GetObjectClass(range);
jmethodID mid_Range_getLower = env->GetMethodID(cls_Range, "getLower", "()Ljava/lang/Comparable;");

jobject lower = env->CallObjectMethod(range, mid_Range_getLower);
jclass cls_Integer = env->GetObjectClass(lower);
jmethodID mid_Integer_intVale = env->GetMethodID(cls_Integer, "intValue", "()I");
jint lowerInt = env->CallIntMethod(lower, mid_Integer_intValue);
```

Comment: Hi Botje, Thank you for replying. For me the object Range itself is correct as I checked it with toString and saw a valid string"[1,100]", however getLower crashes because method getLower not found and following code returns null                                                                     methodID mid_Range_getLower = env->GetMethodID(cls_Range, "getLower", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");

Comment: Ah, I did not look too clearly. T has to be at least Comparable. Updated my answer.

Comment: @NikolaiSemenkov You should approve the answer, then.